# How to select which doctor didn't see any patient?

Tags: sql, ssms

In my table Visits every Doctor have patients. I tried to do it with case but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT DoctorID
    CASE 
    WHEN  COUNT(DISTINCT PatientID) = 0 THEN 'There is no doctor who hasn't admitted any patients. '
    ELSE 'There is no doctor who hasn't admitted any patients.
FROM Visits
GROUP BY DoctorID;
```

Comment: select from doctors left join visits etc.

Comment: @Patrycja, you need to put 2 single quotes in you strings:  'There is no doctor who hasn''t admitted any patients. ' and not 'There is no doctor who hasn't admitted any patients. '.   You guess you are getting an error

Comment: I did also like this ' SELECT d.FistName + ' ' + d.LastName as 'Doctors who has not admitted any patients', COUNT(w.PatientID) as [Patient count]
 FROM Doctors d
 left join Visits v on  d.DoctorID=w.DoctorID
 GROUP BY  d.FistName + ' ' + d.LastName 
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PatientID) = 0;' Its good but i would like to have under first column a text ; There is no doctor who hasn't admitted any patients;

Comment: `'There is no doctor who hasnt admitted any patients. ' as comments ` might help you. Sample code - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bffa3/9/0

Comment: Can you post a sample of desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `not exists`.  If a doctor has seen no patients, then I wouldn't expect that doctor to be in a table called `visits`.  So:

```
select d.*
from doctors d
where not exists (select 1 from visits v where v.doctorid = d.doctorid);
```

Comment: I would like to have in a row under 'Doctors that hasn't seen no patients' column with a text that ' There is no doctor that didnt see any patient'

Answer (score 0):

Would below work?

```
SELECT DoctorID, count(DISTINCT PatientID) 
FROM VISITS
GROUP BY DoctorID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PatientID) = 0
```

Comment: @PatrycjaBobek What do you mean with "added FROM"?